# Creating a grouped Array based on Year from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array that I would like to group by Year. For instance, I have 6 entries into an Array and would like to create a two dimension array grouped by year so 2 entries for each year...

```
[4711.067999999985, 12596.399999999936, 12596.399999999936, "Accessories", "2011"]
[5277939.947800145, 8912342.140000183, 8912342.140000183, "Bikes", "2011"]
[16185.937500000333, 42468.34000000009, 42468.34000000009, "Accessories", "2012"]
[11725882.954398958, 19702448.459998813, 19702448.459998813, "Bikes", "2012"]
[168010.80079996982, 448815.8899998886, 448815.8899998886, "Accessories", "2013"]
[14915767.767399808, 24907912.949997608, 24907912.949997608, "Bikes", "2013"]
```

I would like this to be an Array like...

```
Array[0][0] = [4711.067999999985, 12596.399999999936, 12596.399999999936, "Accessories", "2011"]

Array[0][1] = [5277939.947800145, 8912342.140000183, 8912342.140000183, "Bikes", "2011"]

Array[1][0] = [16185.937500000333, 42468.34000000009, 42468.34000000009, "Accessories", "2012"]
```

So `Array[0]` is `2011`, `Array[1]` is `2012`, `Array[2]` is 2013 etc.

Any idea how to loop through an array and then group by Year?

Comment: Does the year will always be the last index of the array you current have?

Comment: if `Array[0] is 2011` then how come `Array[0][0]` can be some other value. can you show us the output example.

Comment: @CalvinNunes yes-  year is always last

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee currently I just have 6 items in a single array like the above example, i would like to split those 6 items into 1 array that has 3 array's inside of it (for each year)

Comment: Where are you getting stuck with your effort so far? Do you have any code to share yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let data = [ 
  [4711.067999999985, 12596.399999999936, 12596.399999999936, "Accessories", "2011"],
  [5277939.947800145, 8912342.140000183, 8912342.140000183, "Bikes", "2011"],
  [16185.937500000333, 42468.34000000009, 42468.34000000009, "Accessories", "2012"],
  [11725882.954398958, 19702448.459998813, 19702448.459998813, "Bikes", "2012"],
  [168010.80079996982, 448815.8899998886, 448815.8899998886, "Accessories", "2013"],
  [14915767.767399808, 24907912.949997608, 24907912.949997608, "Bikes", "2013"]
]

yearsList= ['2011', '2012', '2013']

groupByYear = {}

yearsList.map((year, index) => {
  groupByYear[index] = [];
  data.map(item => { 
    if(item.includes(year)){
      groupByYear[index].push(item)
    }
  })
})

console.log("groupBy Year", groupByYear, "\n**********END\n\n")

// If you want in 2D array then

let output = Object.values(groupByYear)

console.log("Year 2011 data", output[0]);
console.log("Year 2012 data", output[1]);
console.log("Year 2013 data",output[2]);
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed, This works - how could I modify it to have the index instead of year? -- for instance, instead of 2011, 2012, 2013 being the names of the arrays, 0, 1, 2 are?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the JSON format to save your data (which is working pretty fine with JavaScript as an object). It would look like this:

```
{
  "years": [
    {
      "id": 2011, 
      "value01": 4711.067999999985, 
      "value02": 12596.399999999936, 
      "value03": 12596.399999999936, 
      "type": "Accessories"
    }, 
    {
      "year": 2012, 

      ...

    }
  ]
}
```

Otherwise you just can save every value combined as one string, which is not the best solution to work with later on. You can find some more information on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp).

Answer (score -1):

You could use a hashtable to solve that in O(n):

```
  const results = [], hash = {};

  for(const [v1, v2, v3, category, year] of input) {
    if(!hash[year]) {
      results.push(hash[year] = []);
    }
    hash[year].push([v1, v2, v3, category, year]);
 }
```

Comment: Not sure how to use this... is input support to be the current array?

Comment: @dustin yup, exactly.

Comment: JavaScript objects do not hash the keys

Comment: @user633183 are you sure?

Comment: Yes, it just `toString`s them. `Map` is maybe what you’re thinking of?

Comment: @user633183 no, some engines (e.g. V8) will use hashtables internally for faster key lookup (afaik), i prefer to use objects as they are commonly known & shorter

Comment: @user633183 see https://www.jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation